# How to check if firebase child contains any special value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get users who live in boston. Also I will use this method for other cities. So if it includes "bos" or "bo" I want to get the value anyway. I can't use `equalTo` in this case, because the database contains this words different types like "bostonmelie" "bostonspek".

I tried to use code like this but it didn't work:

```
var myref= firebase.database().ref();

myref.child('Users').orderByChild('Mothclass').on("value", function(snapshot) {
    //console.log(snapshot.val());
    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
        //console.log(data.key);

        var n = data.key.includes("bos");
        console.log(n);


    });
});
```

Console log

```
00jszBe7JKba7DHwZKbK1G9ID7D3 checkfraud.js:105:9
1Fnyqg0T7ldDEPGppu9zOIa66ZE2 checkfraud.js:105:9
2LbwNtF1vWW0AWiKRum45xD04812 checkfraud.js:105:9
2kB7IwMAlzWK6l5T9hWXHUoCiL42 checkfraud.js:105:9
3ASeCkjaxrQrPtelENfkm1XvZfJ3 checkfraud.js:105:9
3JmFZ9fztRbnFhTLIbscp97IXjB3 checkfraud.js:105:9
3i588ADWdsU4PX86wyNnk961GBC2 checkfraud.js:105:9
3p6tvDw3SfdOp2KptgzK0Padn143 checkfraud.js:105:9
3yAWS85t4xc8awxiZhE20qFkUGd2 checkfraud.js:105:9
```

Comment: "it didn't work" is a useless problem description; if it had worked you wouldn't be here. What is logged by the code?

Comment: The code turn "false" on console.

Comment: I have never used firebase, but shouldn't you look in `data.val()` for `"bos"`? Isn't `data.key` the unique ID made of "random" letters and numbers?

Comment: It's contains 2 value.City and last object which is created by user.
Mothclass = city+object;

Comment: ....ok. Just do this: `console.log(data.key);` what do you get?

Comment: All Mothclass object consoled.I get the all Mothclass.

Comment: It would be helpfull if you post the actual example of data here

Comment: I'm sorry ı get the user id's of user's.It's my faul.Here.update first message.

Comment: Right. So these keys obviously don't include `"bos"`. Try `if (data.val().includes("bos")) console.log(data.val());`

Comment: Bu this work "  myref.child('Users').orderByChild('Mothclass').equalTo("bostonmelie").on("value", function(snapshot) { "

Comment: Who cares though? You seem to not understand my extremely basic and straightforward suggestion, so either just try my code and tell us what happens or I'll move on. My second comment should've conclusively solved this question. Not sure what we're still talking about, tbh.

Comment: "TypeError: data.val(...).includes is not a function" Also i tried "data.key" but nothing change.It work when i use the user id like " var n = (data.key).includes("mwcc5zCd");
  console.log(n); " It's turn "false" or "true" under the id.

Comment: So lets go back one step and do `console.log(data.val());` And please, *forget about the key*, since we don't need it for now. You are searching for "bos", so the key is irrelevant.

Comment: Yeep.It's work now i get the all user's objects.But "TypeError: data.val(...).includes is not a function " error still appear on console.

Comment: Yes, probably because `data.val()` returns an object, not a string. The console shows the structure of the object, and you need to include the column name I guess. So something like `data.val().city.includes("bos")`? Do you still not see how this works?

Comment: Now I did.Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To query the database for keys that **start with** `bos`:

```
myref.child('Users').orderByKey().startAt('bos').endAt('bos\uf8ff').on("value", function(snapshot) {
  ...
```

The `\uf8ff` is simply the last known unicode character, so you're selecting all keys in a range that starts with `bos` and ends just before `bot`.

You'll note that I removed the `orderByChild()` call, since Firebase queries can only contain one `orderBy...`. This approach performs the filtering on the server, but that means you must possibly reorder the matching nodes on the client.